# Elasticsearch error failed to connect to master - no route to host

Tags: elasticsearch

When I run elasticsearch 0.90.0 with command: `bin/elasticsearch -f`, I get this error:

```
[2014-09-17 15:00:27,998][INFO ][node                     ] [Myers, Fred] {0.90.0}[8030]: initializing ...
[2014-09-17 15:00:28,005][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Myers, Fred] loaded [], sites []
[2014-09-17 15:00:30,508][INFO ][node                     ] [Myers, Fred] {0.90.0}[8030]: initialized
[2014-09-17 15:00:30,508][INFO ][node                     ] [Myers, Fred] {0.90.0}[8030]: starting ...
[2014-09-17 15:00:30,762][INFO ][transport                ] [Myers, Fred] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.0.108:9301]}
[2014-09-17 15:00:36,874][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [Myers, Fred] failed to connect to master [[Holly][nlr9o-yfSQ6MsTtYlTlqlw][inet[/192.168.1.6:9300]]], retrying...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Holly][inet[/192.168.1.6:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:671)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:610)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:580)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innterJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$500(ZenDiscovery.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:290)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
[2014-09-17 15:00:36,874][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Myers, Fred] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x361eaf47]], closing connection
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-09-17 15:00:42,892][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Myers, Fred] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x2656abc9]], closing connection
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
...
```

I don't install logstash.
When I access `localhost:9200`, I get

```
{
  ok: true,
  status: 503,
  name: "Haywire",
  version: {
    number: "0.90.0",
    snapshot_build: false
  },
  tagline: "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give a name to your cluster and the issue will be solved. 
Edit `config/elasticsearch.yml` in your elasticsearch directory.

Uncomment `cluster.name: elasticsearch` and change it to something like `cluster.name: your_hostname`

Then try to start elasticsearch again.

Comment: IMPOV, Answer has nothing related with the error above.

Comment: It *is* related indeed. Or can be. See the answer from @david_p for a broader explanation and hints for a proper configuration. But you definitly should have a custom cluster name if you don't want an otherwise default configured ElasticSearch to try connecting to other default named clusters in your R&D network ;)

Answer (score 14):

Your ElasticSearch instance is trying to join a cluster (probably someone else on your network) but fails. You should disable automatic cluster discovery.

1. Find the 'Discovery' section in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`
2. Disable multicast discovery (enabled by default) by uncommenting this line:

`# discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false`

**EDIT**: I just discovered that this error can still happen, even when "zen multicast discovery" is disabled. If (like me) you have `network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1` in `elasticsearch.yml` (to only allow local connections to ElasticSearch), you must also set `network.host: 127.0.0.1`. Otherwise, ElasticSearch will not be able to connect to itself (it needs to, for some reason).

Comment: Saving lives! Thank you :) But the file may not be located there. So just find the file in your elastisearch install dir and uncomment this :)

Comment: Thanks dude . I know it is not good to put a comment just to express that but it deserved it !

Comment: `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false` was disabled by default. Enabling it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is someone on your network running elasticsearch and you can't reach their server.  Set your cluster name to something else and you won't run into that problem:

```
bin/elasticsearch --Des.cluster.name=your_name
```

When ES starts up, it uses multicast discovery to find other nodes with the same cluster name.  There is a default clustername of `elasticsearch`, so the multicast is working and finding another ES host.  When you try to join it, it switches to TCP and tries to connect to the IP address directly and your network topology is preventing it (hence the No Route To Host).